# Link SDK and Eclipse JUNO

Tags: eclipse, sdk, adt

I do not know if this forum is for programming questions or for questions related to the development environment.

I have a problem when I start eclipse and says he is the version that I have the 21 and I need 23 or higher.

I'm updating and I get the following error when I try to link the SDK and eclipse.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
  Software currently installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 23.0.4.1468518)
    Hierarchy Viewer 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer [23.0.4.1468518]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer [21.1.0.v201302060044-569685]
```